# Unable to output an image with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "db_test");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tab_gallery`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        header("content-type: image/jpeg");
        $image = $row['f_photo'];
?>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" />
<?php   }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I uploaded a jpeg and I'm trying to output the same image. But what I get in the browser is simply like this.

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned the code above. That is the code, I used to output. I used appgini to upload files into database. File has been uploaded but I'm not able to output it. That's the issue. TIA.

Comment: I meant the generated HTML code you can open in the browser.

Comment: Youre setting the content type as jpeg and then outputting html.  Change the content-type to text/html instead.

Comment: I removed the header function too. It didnt work. still I get the same output.

Comment: Need to see your database or at least your upload script.  Could be something with the blob field or the way you stored it.

Comment: Yeah ! Got it.I used AppGini, a software that automatically creates php files to upload data to the db. The image data (string) was not complete and hence it caused the problem when I tried to recreate the image. Now, I'm able to read the file. Thanks everyone for your inputs.